# How can I get information about a term through JavaScript by giving term name (label)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, term

```
var myTerm = getTermInfo('term name');
```

specially i need to get the GUID of the term, i know that after getting guid i can get all the other properties of that particular term.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the store (by name) then the SP.Taxonomy.TermCollection and then the term by name.

Based on: [Working with Taxonomy and JavaScript in SharePoint 2013](http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_layouts/15/";

    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){

                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", execOperation);

            });
        }
    );

});

function execOperation(){

    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

    //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_name");

    //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
    var termSet = termStore.getTerms();

    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms().getByName("term name");

    context.load(terms);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();

    var termList = "Terms: \n";

        while(termEnumerator.moveNext()){

            var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();

            termList += currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";

        } 

          alert(termList);

    },function(sender,args){

          console.log(args.get_message());

    });

}
```